# Check online or not before data load cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to create a cordova application with angularjs.i am using local storage and all data stored after first load.
if the app is loaded without internet,i need to load data from localstorage else need to load from internet.

```
 onDeviceReady: function() {

     isOffline = 'onLine' in navigator && !navigator.onLine;  

}
```

I will get this status here,but my problem is ,
my angular controller start loading data before

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

This event triggered ,
how to apply online offline logic with angular js and cordova?

Comment: Make use of the network plugin for cordova and get the device connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$watch` here on `'onLine' in navigator && !navigator.onLine;` that will get evaluated on each digest cycle, and will call watch function if value gets changed.

**Code**

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   return 'onLine' in navigator && !navigator.onLine;
}, function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(newValue) {//it means user is online
       //do code here
    }
});
```